# How to load all the Xml files from a folder to an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xmldocument

With my below code, I am able to load one Xml file in XmlDocument xWorkload.

```
XmlDocument xWorkload = new XmlDocument();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var outputxml = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);

            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog(); 
            dlg.FileName = "demo"; // Default file name
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".xml"; // Default file extension
            dlg.Filter = "Xml documents (.xml)|*.xml";  // Filter files by extension


            var result = dlg.ShowDialog();  //Opens the dialog box
            if (result == true)
            {
                xWorkload.Load(dlg.FileName);
                string Path = dlg.FileName.Replace(dlg.SafeFileName, "");
            }
        }
```

Suppose, there are more than one Xml files in a folder,And I want to load all the Xml files in xWorkload, and store those xml files in a string
How shall I do it ?Can this be done in wpf using XmlDocument only(Not Linq).  plz suggest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) to select Xml Files root Directory, then:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = fd.ShowDialog();

if(result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fd.SelectedPath)
                              .Where(p => p.EndsWith(".xml"))
                              .ToArray();
    foreach(var path in files)
    {  
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
        // read Xml file
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a WPF application.

Comment: It doesn't matter.Add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` then you can use FolderBrowserDialog.Also I couldn't see a WPF tag in the question

Comment: In, if(result== DialogResult.OK), Sytem.Nullable<bool> does not contain definition of OK

Comment: USE this: `result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK`

Comment: +1. Side note: You don't need `Where`/`ToArray` as `foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles(fd.SelectedPath, "*.xml"))` would work as well with less extra object and filtering on OS level instead of app level.

Comment: Can this be done without using Winforms and Linq, I mean through XmlDocument only in wpf.

Comment: if you want to use XmlDocument then use it.But I don't know  what do you mean by only WPF?? what is the difference you are  using just a FolderBrowserDialog that's all!

Comment: @Selman22 : How to read the Xml files from XDocument.Load(path), plz suggest.

Comment: @MishraSaurabh take a look at the documentation: [LINQ to XML Programming Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387065.aspx)