# XDocument Load Multiple XML Files From Multiple Folders At Once

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2013, linq-to-xml

How do I load multiple XML files from multiple folders at once using XDocument.Load(paths)?

I am wanting to to this so that I can display each XML file in a webpage.

The file structure is like XMLFiles --> Years --> Months --> files.XML. I want them all loading at once.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with MVC 4.

Comment: single `XDocument` object can only handle one XML

Comment: @har07 Can I do somthing like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423183/how-to-load-all-the-xml-files-from-a-folder-to-an-xmldocument but for multiple folders as well as files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the answer of the question you linked in your comment like so :

```
string xmlFiles = "path_to_XMLFiles_folder/XMLFiles";
                          //get all folders within XMLFiles folder. the years
string[] files = Directory.GetDirectories(xmlFiles)
                          //get all folders within each year. the months
                          .SelectMany(Directory.GetDirectories)
                          //get all files within each montsh.
                          .SelectMany(Directory.GetFiles)
                          .Where(f => f.EndsWith(".xml"))
                          .ToArray();
foreach(var path in files)
{  
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
    //process each XML file
}
```

I'm not sure this will suits your ultimate goal, but anyway, this is what you asked in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has not as many code as @har07 but it is the same:

```
string mainPath = "path where you have all xml"
string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(mainPath, "search pattern as you need", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach(var path in paths){
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
//something you want to do with xml
}
```

I think you will not find another solution.